# Edit how List View web part displays content

Tags: list-view, content-editor-web-part

I need to display profile pics and year of members categorized by Graduation Date.

They are displaying as such, but each profile is taking up a ton of space...

[image]

My goal is to get it to look something like this:

[image]

With an end goal mock up of (with Dates in the middle)

[image]

Do I need to manually put them in a Content Editor Web Part and display them the way I like?

**Question 2:**

How can I change images to be defaulted to all be minimized or all be shown?

[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have the time for a full answer on the steps needed to take but I suggest you research Data View Web Parts via SharePoint Designer. You'll use XSLT along with HTML and CSS to get the formatting you want.

Comment: @ToddersLegrande my company has barred me from editing in SP Designer :( I guess doing it manually via CEWP is the best way to go then?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my blog on XSLT - http://paylord.wordpress.com. You can create the custom XSLT in a separate file and connect it to the web part all without SPD.  The XSLT can live in a normal document library.

Comment: Great blog. This answer would be much more useful if you linked to some relevant posts though. I imagine you were referring to the CQWP and XSLT 1 and 2 posts?

Comment: Thanks - and yes, though there are also XSLT and SharePoint Parts 1-3 which might be simpler if CQWP is not needed in this case?